# Get values from enum field to dynamic populate radio buttons in Vue

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making todo vue component. One of the fields (MySQL table todos) is enum type: priority enum('high', 'medium', 'low'). How can I make radio buttons from that field or should I use some other field type?

I added manually data property with enum field values:

```
data() {
    return {
        priorities: [{ name: 'High' }, { name: 'Medium' } , { name: 'Low' }],
    }
},
```

Then in template dynamically created radio buttons:

```
<label >Priority</label>
<div v-for="(priority, index) in priorities" :key="index">
    <input type="radio" :name="priority.name" :value="priority.name" v-model="form.priority" :id="priority.name">
    <label :for="priority.name">{{ priority.name }}</label>
</div>
```

I want to get default values from enum field.

Comment: As I understand you don't want to manually create enum fields, you want them to come from backend api right?

Comment: You understood right :).

Comment: Okey :) So do you have a backend application that connects to mysql db?

Comment: Sure, made with Laravel. I get data from API, all CRUD is implemented, only default values from enum field are manually created.

Comment: I think you can create a new endpoint called getPriorities and fetch that endpoint with fetch api or axios

Comment: But i don't know how to fetch default values from enum field, stored values are not problem :(

Comment: Oh I understand the problem now, we should be able to convert enum types to string in mysql db, thats tricky...